# Making a page that appears only upon first time opening the app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my app I want the user to see this startup/welcome page when the app launches and then click a button on it to go to login and continue using the app… and next time he opens the app the app doesn't show the startup screen and goes straight to the login or home screen... I have made a storage service that saves a state if the page has been seen and a page guard that redirects based on the state...

But now I have an issue that my app keeps skipping the startup page and goes straight to login and when I try to log in it stays on this page… the console.log show that the state is set to 'done'…

here is my code if anyone can figure out what I did wrong...

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule),
    canLoad: [AutoLoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'startup',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'startup',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/startup/startup.module').then( m => m.StartupPageModule),
    canActivate:[FirstLoadGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

this is the code of **storage.service.ts:**

```
export class StorageService {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    this.initStorage();
    console.log('Init storage');
  }

  async initStorage() {
    await this.storage.create();
    console.log('Storage ustvarjen');
  }

  async setValue(key,value) {
    await this.storage.set(key, value);
    return true;
  }

  async getValue(key) {
    return await this.storage.get(key);
  }
}
```

this is the **first-load.guard.ts:**

```
export class FirstLoadGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):  Promise<boolean>
  {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storageService.getValue('first_time').then((value) => {
        if (value !== null) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          console.log('guard if value: ', value);
          resolve(false);
        }
        else {
          this.storageService.setValue('first_time', 'done');
          resolve(true);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

If I have to provide more code, feel free to comment bellow and I'll add more... I trully don't know where my mistake is :(

Comment: IIndeed, it would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: From what you said it should be as simple as writing an entry to the localstorage once the user  logs in and once he does your logic can decide the next view based on this entry.

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: @Cuzy I want the startup screen to be shown before user comes to the login...

Comment: @weinde Well, it's the same thing really, you write an entry to `localStorage` when the user first enters the page and based on that you can redirect him the next time they visit the page.

Comment: @Cuzy here is the link to stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-valxtn?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [canMatch](https://angular.io/api/router/CanMatch) to check on the same patch, and you don't need to do redirects

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/startup/startup.module').then( m => m.StartupPageModule),
    canMatch: [() => localStorage.getItem('first_time') === null],
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, this is giving me an issue that when i load the app the startup page is shown for a few second and it auto redirects to home, i want it to stay n that page until user click a button on it

Comment: @weinde you have some redirect in `./pages/startup/startup.module`

Comment: @weinde add `RouterModule.forRoot(..., { enableTracing: true })` to see where the redirect is from

Comment: No I don't... could it be that the page auto redirects once the state is set?

Comment: canMatch only checks when is trigger navigation

Comment: Ok, so I added that code to RouterModule... what part do I copy for you to see? there is a lot of messages in console now...

Comment: could there be something wrong whit another part of my code? since after the value is set in storage and if i navigate back to /startup in url bar the page stays there... which is the opposite of what I want

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out :) I had a redirect in some other file... your answer worked and I am accepting it :) Thank you soo much :) If i could id take u out for a beer now :)

Comment: Altho when I close the app on my phone and launh it again, i still keep seeing the startup page...

Comment: @weinde try to implement `runGuardsAndResolvers`